# How to check if an Active Directory group is a member of a another Active Directory group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, active-directory-group

Suppose user johnsmith is a member of an active directory group MyManagers.
Suppose group MyManagers is a member of the group MyEmployees.
Suppose group MyEmployees is a member of the group MyUsers.

When johnsmith logs in to my application, how can I know that he is a member of the group MyUsers?

Appreciate examples in C#.

Thanks,
kruvi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current; // this would be John Smith

if(user != null)
{
   // get the user's groups he's a member of
   PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

   // now you just need to iterate over the groups and see if you find the
   // one group you're interested in
}
```

The `GetAuthorizationGroups` call in S.DS.AM does indeed do recursive querying, e.g. it will also pick up any groups your user is a member of because of groups being members of other groups.

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!